# Magento 2 : Quote returns empty

Tags: magento2, quote

I'm trying to get quote but It return me empty(null).

I'm trying to get this is `addToCart.phtml` file where it returns empty. 
and i tried at `Magento_Checkout` where it works pretty great.

Dont know what's wrong below:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
?>
```

**Any Help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Can you tell me, in which file you tried this code? i mean .php or .phtml

Comment: addToCart.phtml IN vendor for now.

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code**

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
foreach($itemsCollection as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
?>
```

**I hope it will help...!!!**

Comment: already tried not working.

Comment: @Vivek heve you tried checkout session to get cart items?

Comment: did you find any solution?